# Finding volume of a revolution

Tags: integration, volume

I want to find the volume of the revolution that occurs when the region bounded by $y = x^2$ and $y = 1$ is revolved around the line $y=2$. The problem is that it is not solid and I cannot understand how the disk method could be used. How can one attack the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disk method can be used here. $V = \displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 \pi\left((2-x^2)^2-1^2\right)dx$

Comment: You should elaborate, as answers to homework problems are frowned upon. Cheers.